# Set up include path in node.js (express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I want to deploy node.js application from my own upstart script and cron. The app starts but doesn't work because can't include files. I have errors:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "front/index"
```

How to set up the include path ?

Comment: Can you add your upstart .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `chdir /path/to/your/app` directive in your upstart configuration. By default, express will use the process's working directory to look up views. You can also use `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` to set a particular directory, but given that your app works locally, your problem is almost certainly lack of `chdir` in your upstart configuration.